# At Up To together in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Does it make sense to say "At Up To 30% off"?
Shouldn't it either be "At" or "Up To"...not "At Up To"?

Answer (score 2):

"At 30% off" would mean that all items are reduced by 30%.

"Up to 30%" means that the price reduction may be 30%, or it may be a smaller reduction, such as 25%.

Therefore *up to* is essential to preserve the intended meaning.  *At* may be optional, depending on the context.

Comment: I'm not sure the At is always optional.  E.g. a sentence like  "At up to 30% off, these deals can't be missed" seems to require the At.